# Cannot run flutter project, facebook problem

Tags: facebook, flutter

I have a flutter project with facebook login but when I try to run it I got some errors.... I already update pods and Flutter plugins and also clean the project. Everything is good. These are the errors I got.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             33,2s
Running Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                           12,9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKDeviceLoginManager.m:138:42: error: no known
    class method for selector 'fbErrorWithDomain:code:message:underlyingError:'
            NSError *wrappedError = [NSError fbErrorWithDomain:FBSDKLoginErrorDomain
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKDeviceLoginManager.m:148:31: error: no known
    class method for selector
    'extractPermissionsFromResponse:grantedPermissions:declinedPermissions:'
            [FBSDKInternalUtility extractPermissionsFromResponse:permissionResult
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKDeviceLoginManager.m:151:67: error: no visible
    @interface for 'FBSDKAccessToken' declares the selector
    'initWithTokenString:permissions:declinedPermissions:appID:userID:expirationDate:refreshDate:
    dataAccessExpirationDate:'
            FBSDKAccessToken *accessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken alloc]
            initWithTokenString:tokenString
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKDeviceLoginManager.m:215:44: error: no known
    class method for selector 'fbErrorWithDomain:code:message:'
              NSError *unknownError = [NSError fbErrorWithDomain:FBSDKLoginErrorDomain
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    4 errors generated.
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.m:209:25: error: no known class
    method for selector 'currentAccessTokenIsActive'
      if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessTokenIsActive]) {
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/eulalia/Downloads/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master/ios/Pods/FB
    SDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.m:315:47: error: no known class
    method for selector 'currentAccessTokenIsActive'
      BOOL accessTokenIsValid = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessTokenIsActive];
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 errors generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.

If someone can help me with this I appreciate..

Regards,

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Want to put your podfile and pubspec in here?

I've got the same problem now.  My guess (based on how other things have gone with Firebase+flutter) is that you have conflicting Firebase packages/versions